# Selecting name with 5 or more characters from table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to select a random name from a table, but I need the name's length to be more than 5 character. How do I say that in SQL?

```
SELECT name FROM tableName WHERE rand() AND (name longer than 5 characters)
```

Comment: `5 or more` vs. `name longer than 5`

Comment: IN addition to the solution with LENGTH see this : http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) in where clause, see example below:

```
SELECT name FROM tableName WHERE rand() AND length(name) > 5
```

Additionally, you may add `LIMIT` to get number of records you needed (and that much existed in your table).

Comment: This will do it fine (well, with a LIMIT 1 added). Down side is that ORDER BY RAND() is not very efficient. Depending on the amount of data it might be worthwhile doing it a faster way.

Comment: usually people looking for random are more consumed by variety (in a pseudo-random world) than efficiency :> Come up with a creative seed for the RNG

Comment: Aye @Drew , but if it were a table with 1m users with a name over 5 characters long the response time might make them suddenly start contemplating efficiency!

Comment: maybe a denormalized table with a nameLen column and an index. I am sure Jessica will be all over that when it grows :>

Comment: Why has this been edited to remove the ORDER BY RAND() that had been added and which would work?

Comment: @Kickstart, order by removed as you said _ORDER BY RAND() is not very efficient depending on the amout of data_ , however  `where rand()` also works well - tested

Comment: Not sure it will work well. I would expect that RAND() will return a random value of 0 or more but less than 1, Mysql will then probably evaluate that as a boolean, but most will evaluate to true and the order will be the default. Hence likely the random row returned will be the first one on the table, and if not the 2nd or 3rd.